# Как раздать Wi-fi с ноутбука по протоколу 802.11ax.?

Tags: wifi, ноутбук

Мне надо раздать Wifi с ноута на частоте 5ghz, причем желательно по протоколу wifi 6e (802.11ax), разумеется модуль в ноуте поддерживает этот протокол. Итак, в чем соль. В параметрах виндовс есть раздел хотспот, там по идее можно раздать wifi на частоте 5ггц, однако что странно, если подключится к домашней точке 2ггц, то даже если выставить в этих параметрах 5ггц, хотспот будет раздаваться на частоте 2ггц. Нашел решение (костыль), если раздать точку 5ггц с телефона, подключится к ней с ноута и только потом дать хотспот, то вот он уже будет работать на частоте 5ггц, но по протоколу wifi5 (802.11ac).

Писал в поддержку Микрософт, там мне сказали обновить винду и если не поможет, то увы, ничем не помочь. Софта для раздачи почти нет, а тот что есть не функционален. Может кто нибудь знает какую нибудь волшебную софтинку, или может объяснить почему это невозможно.